# Removing undesired left indent on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, indentation

I have a Table View within my main UIViewController that has one non-editable prototype cell. I am trying to remove the left indent from the table view cell. No matter what method I use, the indent does not go away.

**Here is what I have tried:**

- On the Table View: In Interface Builder > Attributes Inspector, I set Separator Inset to Custom with left inset of 0.
- On the Table View Cell: In Interface Builder > Attributes Inspector, I set indentation Level and Width to 0. I also changed Separator to Custom with left 0.

I also tried the following in code:

```
myTable.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
myTable.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

And this inside of cellForRowAt:indexPath

```
cell.indentationLevel = 0
cell.indentationWidth = 0
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
return cell
```

Here's a screenshot of what's occurring:

[image: Undesired left indent]

I need all of the "Hello's" to left-align with the red section header text.

How can I remove the left-indent of the content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a custom cell with a label and at the required distance from the left edge?

Comment: This worked great. My head was spinning trying to kill the left indent on the default table cell... All I needed to do was subclass UITableViewCell, create my custom label, and register it in cellForRow.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help:D

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that layoutMargins is the reason of indent on UITableViewCell. But I think you can't change layoutMargins. I almost don't use textLabel of UITableViewCell. You can refer to [Setting layoutMargins of UIView doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421469/setting-layoutmargins-of-uiview-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```
helloLabel.textAlignment = .Left
cell.addSubview(helloLabel)
```