# How to change the layout margins programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have very easy setup in `viewDidLoad`, just add a view and pin it to superview's margins by 'anchors' style:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: .zero)
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(myView)
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
view.layoutMargins = .zero
```

The problem is that there is still a margin when running this in simulator. Why layoutMargins zeroing is ignored?

[image]

Comment: if you want zero why don´t use `view.leadingAnchor`directly?

Comment: I can't. This is very simplified case from some project. I am not building a red rectangle app :-)

Comment: OK, I was suspecting that, so there is my answer to your problem

Comment: also I think the proper name for this answer is How change the margins size programatically since this is your main issue or I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed/changed for `iOS 11`. Lower versions are out of luck.

I've elaborated more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421469/setting-layoutmargins-of-uiview-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

You need add this in your `UIViewController` `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` method

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    view.layoutMargins = .zero
    view.layoutMarginsDidChange()
}
```

but if you need `.zero` of margins you can as I said in my comments use `view.leadingAnchor` as well

Comment: Hmmm, this will be called multiple times. It's working though. Isn't there any other place/way to do this just once? I don't want to change it dynamically during the view life cycle.

Comment: @ViktorKucera check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421469/setting-layoutmargins-of-uiview-doesnt-work seems this is the best shot we have, but you can add an subview as alternative solution

Comment: yes, is ignored indeed for me is an Apple mistake but is what we have so... no much left to do about it @ViktorKucera

Comment: It's fixed in iOS11, I've just tried in Xcode beta. Thanks for help.

Comment: I am glad to hear that seems Apple is fixing his bugs, @ViktorKucera

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
   viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins = false
   view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2891115-viewrespectssystemminimumlayoutm) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `self.view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false` which will add on to whatever values you set to `self.view.directionalLayoutMargins` or `self.view.layoutMargins`