# UITableViewHeaderFooterView custom layoutMargins

Tags: ios, user-interface, layout

I am trying to setup my own `layoutMargins` for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass. I have a header defined in a xib and loaded inside `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)`. This is the snippet:

```
class SomeHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layoutMargins = .zero
        contentView.layoutMargins = .zero
    }
}
```

It's still 20 points for any iPhone.

[image]

I am aware of [problems with a root views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421469/setting-layoutmargins-of-uiview-doesnt-work). Is this the same problem? No way to customize than create my own contentView or something like that?