# imageView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero has no effect in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, ios12

I have some configuration based on the type of data I receive ( the insets to add in the cell.configure(with item: item) {}, however the cells are not re-used properly. I am using RxSwift for binding, though I don't see the issue in there.

tried setting `image.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero` in `prepareForReuse()`, in the `cell.configure(with: item)` etc. Doesn't seem to work.

```
    brandsGroup
        .bind(to: rx.items(cellIdentifier: StudioCellConstants.brandReuseIdentifier,
                           cellType: BrandCollectionViewXibCell.self)) { (_, item, cell) in
                            cell.configure(with: item)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    image.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

Update:

Eventually I ended up setting back the frame like this, but it feels like a hacky solution.
   A better way would be much appreciated.

```
                image.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: imageContainerView.frame.width, height: imageContainerView.frame.height)
```

Comment: Elaborate this statement what does that mean cells are not re-used properly ?? 
what they are doing and what you want to achieve?  tell your exacti issue and attach some screenShots of what you want and what you are currently getting?

Comment: the UIEdgeInsets of the UIImageView are not reset when the model changes. ( read prepareForReuse() is called) setting UIEdgeInsets manually doesn't seem to work as well. I can't see why...

Comment: before calling cell.configure(with: item)
place following 
image.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

Comment: or show us cell.configure method

Comment: tried that, does not work. The cell configure method is an if/else statement which sets the insets based on a condition. I am using the instance method on the called withAlignmentRectInsets(_:)

Comment: thats what i am saying  set insets in both if and also in else condition too like 
if true {
set margin 
}else
{
reset margin or margin for else condition.
}
reason. tableView resuses cell so instead of using new cell tableView uses one of old cell that have layout margin set, so it appears to be faulty

Comment: if you show configure cell method i can elaborate that according to your scenario.

Comment: nope, that's not the problem :) It is either something related to cell re-usage which I don't know about, some drawing thing related to UIKit.

Comment: i have gone through if else condtion in cellForRow and cellForItem many times :) next its upto you, i alwasy found solution setting an alternative values for else conditions :) happy coding

Comment: I eventually ended up setting the frame back like this:     image.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: imageContainerView.frame.width, height: imageContainerView.frame.height)) but it feels like a hack.

Comment: okay great, go with it until someday you will understand what the problem was and then replace it ;)

Comment: also here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421469/setting-layoutmargins-of-uiview-doesnt-work
Custom layoutMargin cannot work

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the content fill mode of imageview in cell correctly.

```
//Swift code(I am not familier in rxswift but the concept should be the same)

 let imageView = UIImageView()  
 imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

I prefered `scaleAspectFill` here as I assume u need the image to cover the whole `imageView`

Comment: thanks for the reply, though I don't see how is this related to my question. Setting the scale does not help.  The content mode I have is image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit.

Comment: please check the question comments above

Comment: There are many ways this could happen. but most possible outcome is the improper way of reusing cells..Check if your configuring the cell values each time a model is updated in cellForRow. Good luck

Comment: yes, I checked that. The obvious answers didn't work, thus ended up on StackOverflow.