# Is layoutMarginsGuide seems to be kind of excessive?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

When i was trying to create layout constraints, i read about NSLayoutAnchor class. They said:

> Note
>
> UIView does not provide anchor properties for the layout margin
>   attributes. Instead, the layoutMarginsGuide property provides a
>   UILayoutGuide object that represents these margins. Use the guide’s
>   anchor properties to create your constraints

Ok. But simultaneously I crated anchor properties for the layout margin properties without UILayoutGuide property.

```
     let inputsContainerView = UIView()
    inputsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    inputsContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)

    //need x,y,width,height constraints
    inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
```

So then why do we need UILayoutGuide object? And it turns out UIView does provide anchor properties for the layout margin attributes? Please if someone know anything I would very appreciated.

Comment: The anchors provided by UIView are based on its bounds. The anchors provided by the layoutMarginGuide are based on its margins. UIView margins could be provided by the system and may change within the lifecycle of the view, like on screen rotation. So to add constraints based on the view margins instead of its actual bounds, you can use the anchors provided by layoutMarginGuide.
`view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anotherView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on your design requirements.

[`layoutMarginsGuide` documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622651-layoutmarginsguide):

> A layout guide representing the view’s margins.
>   Use this layout guide’s anchors to create constraints with the view’s margin.

Where Layout Margins is basically just the [safe area](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area) of a view:

> Safe areas help you place your views within the visible portion of the overall interface. UIKit-defined view controllers may position special views on top of your content. For example, a navigation controller displays a navigation bar on top of the underlying view controller’s content. Even when such views are partially transparent, they still occlude the content that is underneath them.

For `self.view`, the visible portion of the overall interface would exclude the areas taken up by status bar, navigation bar, tab bar, etc.
For a normal `UIView`, the default padding is 8px.

So basically, if you want `someView` to be constrained within the safe area / margin of `otherView`, then you will reference `otherView`'s `layoutMarginsGuide` anchors.
If not, then just `otherView`'s anchors are enough.

#### 1. Example (with `layoutMarginsGuide`):

```
let textField = UILabel()
textField.text = "Using Layout Margins Guide Anchors"
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(textField)

var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
//textfield's top edge = self.view's margin's top edge
constraints.append(textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor))

//textfield's leading edge = self.view's margin's leading edge
constraints.append(textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor))

//textfield's trailing edge = self.view's margin's trailing edge
constraints.append(textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor))

//Apply the constraints
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Output:

[image: On layoutMarginsGuide]

Observation:

- Leaves 20px from `self.view`'s left/right edges
- Starts immediate below status bar

  - If you had a navigation bar then it would start below that
- These are `self.view`'s safe area / layout margins

---

#### 2. Example (without `layoutMarginsGuide`):

```
let textField = UILabel()
textField.text = "Without Layout Margins Guide Anchors"
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(textField)

var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
//textfield's top edge = self.view's top edge
constraints.append(textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor))

//textfield's leading edge = self.view's leading edge
constraints.append(textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor))

//textfield's trailing edge = self.view's trailing edge
constraints.append(textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor))

//Apply the constraints
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Output:
[image: On View Anchors alone]

Observation:

- Starts immediately from `self.view`'s left/right edges
- Starts immediately from `self.view`'s top edge which overlaps the status bar

  - If there was a navigation bar, it would overlap too
- These are `self.view`'s bounds

---

Finally, it depends on your requirement.
Sometimes you **should** use it, sometimes you **could** use it, sometimes you just don't need to use it.

PS: Now, whether you base it on the `UIView`'s anchors or it's `layoutMarginsGuide` anchors, it will respond to device rotation or any other layout changes automatically.

Comment: Then how is `layoutMarginsGuide` different from `safeAreaLayoutGuide`?

Comment: @Legonaftik This answer was specific to `layoutMarginsGuide`. For your concern on `layoutMarginsGuide` vs `safeAreaLayoutGuide`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614397/2857130)